# Android make a application which runs over main ui

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I want to make an app which runs over main ui android which have it's own layout and can't be closed ever till i force close it or uninstall it.

Comment: That's great. Do you have a specific programming question?

Answer (score 0):

By default your activity will be the current running activity, of it is open. It will be with your layout, and user can push it to stack using home button, you can block the back button but blocking out overriding home button is not possible

Answer (score 0):

At the app level, you do not have such control.  Nor should you.